# Python 3, Lock base install

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a way to lock the base Python (global?) so that no manual libraries can be installed?  I want to ensure I do not accidentally add anything globally and force everything into my virtual environments.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Strange but could you not create the venv normally and then remove pip? I guess alternatively you could have some reference to the "correct" base and then check/purge all additional files

Comment: You might want to add a tag for the virtual environment tool you're using, like [tag:virtualenv] or [tag:conda].

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I can create venvs without a problem.  I want to make it so I am forced to use a venv so my global python install never changes, e.g. so I cannot add libraries to the main python path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your site-packages to read-only, that way Python won't be able to install any external libraries.

Make sure you remove the read-only status from the `__pycache__` otherwise you won't be able to compile the Python modules.

Comment: Do I do that by setting the folder properties to read only or is there a command within Python.  I looked at the Python documentation and searched Google, but found nothing helpful.

Comment: @Uziel folder properties, read-only